# How can I use an input text box in TableItem of IBM Carbon Design(Angular)?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using table component with dynamic content of carbon design system from [here](https://angular.carbondesignsystem.com/?path=/story/components-table--with-dynamic-content). 
I want to use input text fields which will represent TableItem in the table.

Below is my code

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.model.data = [
            [new TableItem({ data: "Sample 1" }), new TableItem({ data: "Sample 2" }), new TableItem({ data: "Sample 3" })],

    ];

    this.model.header = [
            new TableHeaderItem({ data: "Source Name" }),
            new TableHeaderItem({ data: "Source Identifier" }),
            new TableHeaderItem({ data: "Description" }),
        ];
  }
```

Can someone please suggest me a way through which I can achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkqLq.png) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[carbon-components-angular documentation](https://angular.carbondesignsystem.com/documentation/components/Table.html) might help here.

You'll need to create a template to display your custom data and then pass the template reference, along with the data, to the item where you want to use it.

Template:

```
 <ng-template #customTableItemTemplate let-data="data">
     <a [routerLink]="data.link">{{data.name}} {{data.surname}}</a>
 </ng-template>
```

`let-data=data` gives you access to the data passed to the `TableItem` you're using the template in.

Passing the template to items:

```
customTableItemTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

 this.customModel.data = [
     [new TableItem({data: "asdf"}), new TableItem({data: {name: "Lessy", link: "/table"}, template: this.customTableItemTemplate})],
     [new TableItem({data: "csdf"}), new TableItem({data: "swer"})],
     [new TableItem({data: "bsdf"}), new TableItem({data: {name: "Alice", surname: "Bob"}, template: this.customTableItemTemplate})],
     [new TableItem({data: "csdf"}), new TableItem({data: "twer"})],
 ];
```

Note the `template` part in `new TableItem({data: {name: "Lessy", link: "/table"}, template: this.customTableItemTemplate})`

Now that you know how to use custom templates in tables, only thing left is picking what kind of input component you wish to use and using it in the template.
Make sure to include proper modules for all the components in your app module or equivalent.

This should be enough to get you going.

Cheers, Zvonimir